# how to correctly determine the parameters of the model?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, math, scipy

How can I find the parameters of the model?

model is: `y = a * log(x + b) + c`
and I would like to find `a, b , c.`

of course `x` and `y` is a set of numbers (let's assume it is random because it's not about the whole solution for me).

I am thinking about using the `numpy.polyfit` function, but not too much about what parameters to enter and what to do next.

Could someone tell me more or less how should I go about it?

Comment: Check out [`scipy.optimize.curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html).  The docstring includes an example that you could modify to match your function.

Answer (score 1):

In order to talk about finding parameters of a model, you need some sort of loss function (function you want to minimize). Otherwise your parameters could be anything and you could say you have successfully found the parameters of your model.

Once you have that loss function, you can use an algorithm like gradient-descent. I'd recommend using TensorFlow for this. You first need to define the model using TensorFlow's ops (they have pretty much everything), in order for their algorithm to find how to minimize the loss function. Here is how you would do it:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# I need to use Layer to be able to add parameters by hand
class CustomModel(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomModel, self).__init__()
        
        self.b = self.add_weight(name="b", shape=[1], dtype=tf.float32, trainable=True)
        self.c = self.add_weight(name="c", shape=[1], dtype=tf.float32, trainable=True)
     
     def call(self, x):
         return tf.math.log(x + self.b) + self.c

model = CustomModel()
```

Then you can compile the model using your loss function and train it on the (x, y) pairs.

```
model.compile(loss=SOME_LOSS_FUNCTION, optimizer="adam")
model.fit(x=x, y=y, batch_size=SOME_BATCH_SIZE, epochs=SOME_EPOCHS)
```

It's important to mention that if your problem is just some form of regression you can just set the loss to tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError().

An alternative that might be better in simple cases is to calculate the derivatives by hand and then implement them. That will allow you to keep using numpy ops. However TensorFlow can allow you to take advantage of  a GPU or TPU, so it can be argued that you should use it or any other popular ML framework.

Answer (score 0):

[`scipy.optimize.curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html#scipy-optimize-curve-fit) is what you need - you pass to it the function that you want to fit, a vector of independent variables and a vector of observations, the function return a vector of observed parameters and a covariance matrix.
[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

a0, b0, c0 = 3, 2, 7
x = np.linspace(0,10,1001)
y0 = a0 * np.log(x+b0) + c0
y1 = y0 + np.random.randn(1001)/5

(a1, b1, c1), cov = curve_fit(lambda x, a, b, c: a*np.log(x+b)+c, x, y1)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2,1)
ax1.plot(x, y1, label='Measured')
ax2.plot(x, y0, label='"True", a=%.3f, b=%.3f, c=%.3f'%(a0,b0,c0))
ax2.plot(x, a1*np.log(x+b1)+c1, label='Recovered, a=%.3f, b=%.3f, c=%.3f'%(a1,b1,c1))
ax1.legend()
ax2.legend()
plt.show()
```